# Nautilus multihop ssh

Tags: networking, nautilus, ssh, virtualization

I would like to use the nautilus (or any other usable GUI file manager) to work on Virtual machine. This VM is running on a remote server, and I can't reach it via ssh from my computer, I have to connect the remote server via ssh, and I can only reach the VM from there with (local IP) ssh connection.

Is it possible to use a GUI file manager to view files on remote server from my machine?

Is there any way to simplify this connection?

The best related article, what I found didn't helped: [Transparent Multi-hop SSH](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is what you are looking for, but I am not 100% sure. I am not at home to test it, but I think you can connect trough ssh and then in filezilla you can create a socks proxy.
I think you do need to allow SFTP connection on your remote machine, but it can be done very easy and there are a lot of tutorials.

Comment: I tried this solution, but never worked, so I continue the development with scp workaround.